# Grant WPF application access to local drive?

Tags: c#, wpf, security, permissions, streamwriter

I'm writing an application in C# (it's very basic, for a friend of mine), but I have a StreamWriter object that creates a local file in C:. I have to do Run as Administrator, and it works fine, but otherwise it crashes with "Access to the path 'C:\final.html' is denied."

I've never worked with any sort of security or permissions in code before. What can I do to grant it access to that folder without having to run as administrator?

EDIT: Here's what I ended up doing:

```
string desktop = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
using (StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(desktop, "final.html"))
{
    //...additional code

    output.Write(inputArray.Substring(lastIndex, range.Start - lastIndex));

    //...additional code

    output.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you should be writing to the local user's Application Settings or Documents folder, not the root drive. Use `ApplicationData` or `Personal` from [`Environment.SpecialFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx).

Comment: To go on: there is nothing WPF specific to the security query - Modern Windows will demand a UAC confirmation for ANY file creation in the root. Applications simply are not supposed to do that. NO application, WPF or otherwise.